# How to store array in address C

Tags: c, pointers, lexical-analysis

basically we are provided with the main function:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <strings.h>
 #define STORAGE 255     
 {
 int c;
 char s[STORAGE];

 for(;;) {
    (void) printf("n=%d, s=[%s]\n", c = getword(s), s);
    if (c == -1)break;
    }}
```

we are not to change that

and we have to create the function getword() which should contain a loop that reads a characters,

store it in a array in the address provided one by one and it should stop for whitespace (tab, space, eof)

basically i have this:

```
int getword(char *w)
 {
  char str[255];         
   int i = 0;              
   int charCount = 0;      



printf("enter your sentence:\n");   
gets(str);

   /*this was provided by the professor, but i'm not sure how to use it
   while (( iochar - getchar()) !=EOF);
   */

   for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)           //loop that checks tab and spaces
        {
            if(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t')
            {
                charCount++;
            }
        }

  printf("your string: '%s' contains %d of letters\n", str, charCount); 

  return 0;}
```

right now the output of the program is:

```
 enter your sentence:
 hey stockoverflow
 your string: 'hey stockoverflow' contains 16 of letters
 n=0, s=[]
```

so i'm saving the string and counting it, but i'm not storing it where i should be.

<s>it should display n=16, s=[hey stockoverflow]</s>

actually it should display n=3, s=[hey]

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)           //loop that checks tab and spaces
{
    if(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t')
    {
         charCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        str[i] = '\0'; // Terminate str
        break;         // Break out of the for-loop
    }
}

printf("your string: '%s' contains %d of letters\n", str, charCount); 

strcpy(w, str); // Add this line to copy str into w (which is s from main)

return strlen(w); // Return the length of the result string
```

Comment: perfect, this works correctly now.

any idea on what i should do for the n = 0?
would i create a new loop?